# Live transcript from network stream using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

We are planning a POC where we feed a multicast stream of, say, a press conference to SpeechRecognizer, hoping to get a "live" transcript that we could then use for live subtitling. So far I see two challenges with this:

The first is that I don't know how to "grab" a multicast stream and feed this to the SpeechRecognizer. If anyone would be willing to share a code example showing how to do this (preferably in C#), that would be very helpful.

The other thing is related to timing. I have done some preliminary testing using mic input, and when the speech is more or less continuous, the service processes quite large chunks of speech at a time, resulting in a considerable delay before I get anything back, which would not be ideal in a live subtitling scenario. Is there some setting I can use to change the "granularity" in order to get smaller chunks back more frequently (if that makes sense)?

Any and all input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

sorry, no experience with multicast streams.

For speech recognition, you can subscribe to final results and intermediate results during continuous recognition. Final results are created once the speech recognition engine recognizes a 'segment' of speech. Much more frequent you will receive intermediate recognition events, that give you intermediate results about the speech recognition process. These might change during the recognition, but you will see that they become more and more 'stable' as the speech recognition process proceeds.

Wolfgang

Comment: Thanks, Wolfgang. Yes, I know the intermediate/final flow, but I was wondering whether there's a way to get smaller and more frequent "final" segments.

Answer (score 0):

As Wolfgang mentioned above, for continuous speech, you can subscribe to the `Recognizing` event to receive periodic updates to the predicted spoken text. The `Recognized` event will fire when Azure Speech Service determines the user has stopped speaking.

Example:

```
    var microphone = string.IsNullOrEmpty(file);
    var audio = microphone
        ? AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput()
        : AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput(file);

    var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(key, region);
    var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config);

    recognizer.SessionStarted += SessionStarted;
    recognizer.SessionStopped += SessionStopped;
    recognizer.Recognizing += Recognizing;
    recognizer.Recognized += Recognized;
    recognizer.Canceled += Canceled;

    recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync().Wait();
    if (microphone) { Console.WriteLine("Listening; press ENTER to stop ...\n"); }

    var timeout = _values.GetOrDefault("recognize.timeout", _microphone ? 30000 : int.MaxValue);
    WaitForContinuousStopCancelKeyOrTimeout(recognizer, timeout);

    recognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync().Wait();
```

with event handlers like these:

```
    private void Recognizing(object sender, SpeechRecognitionEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZING: {e.Result.Text}");
    }

    private void Recognized(object sender, SpeechRecognitionEventArgs e)
    {
        var result = e.Result;
        if (result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech && result.Text.Length != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZED: {result.Text}");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        else if (result.Reason == ResultReason.NoMatch && _verbose)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

When run, as I spoke the phrase "My name is Rob Chambers and this is a test of speech recognition", output appears very quickly (within 700-1000ms of each word I spoke):

```
    Listening; press ENTER to stop ...

    RECOGNIZING: my
    RECOGNIZING: my name
    RECOGNIZING: my name is
    RECOGNIZING: my name
    RECOGNIZING: my name is
    RECOGNIZING: my name is rob
    RECOGNIZING: my name is rob chambers
    RECOGNIZING: my name is rob chambers and
    RECOGNIZING: my name is rob chambers and this
    RECOGNIZING: my name is rob chambers and this
    RECOGNIZING: my name is rob chambers and this is
    RECOGNIZING: my name is rob chambers and this is
    RECOGNIZING: my name is rob chambers and this is a
    RECOGNIZING: my name is rob chambers and this is a test
    RECOGNIZING: my name is rob chambers and this is a test of
    RECOGNIZING: my name is rob chambers and this is a test of speech
    RECOGNIZING: my name is rob chambers and this is a test of
    RECOGNIZING: my name is rob chambers and this is a test of speech
    RECOGNIZING: my name is rob chambers and this is a test of speech recognition
    RECOGNIZED: My name is Rob Chambers and this is a test of speech recognition.
```

When i spoke nearly the same phrase, but as two sentences with a very brief pause between them, output appears as follows:

```
    Listening; press ENTER to stop ...

    RECOGNIZING: my
    RECOGNIZING: my name
    RECOGNIZING: my name is
    RECOGNIZING: my name is
    RECOGNIZING: my name is rob
    RECOGNIZING: my name is rob chambers
    RECOGNIZED: My name is Rob Chambers.

    RECOGNIZING: this
    RECOGNIZING: this is a
    RECOGNIZING: this is a test
    RECOGNIZING: this is a test of
    RECOGNIZING: this is a test of speech
    RECOGNIZING: this is a test of speech recognition
    RECOGNIZED: This is a test of speech recognition.
```

Comment: Thanks Rob! I agree, the RECOGNIZING events happen very quickly, but I don't quite see how we could use those for producing live subtitles, as the content can often change significantly between RECOGNIZING events...? Also, capitalization and punctuation only appears in RECOGNIZED events. My assumption was that the algorithm is based on a combination of pause recognition and a buffer size or timeout when deciding when a chunk of text should be returned in a "recognized" event. If so, I was hoping it might be possible to change those parameters somehow in order to achieve different granularity.